# SPAN next to each other WITHOUT float

Tags: css, html

How would you get three span's to sit side by side instead of going to the next line without using float in CSS? So I need all three of these to appear next to each other..or if there is another method without using float.
Thanks!

```html
<span style="display:block; width:33%;">Test1</span>
<span style="display:block; width:33%;">Test2</span>
<span style="display:block; width:33%;">Test3</span>
```

Comment: Why can't you use float? This is exactly what it's meant for. (And inline-block support is pretty flaky)

Comment: @David, inline-block support should be fine. I think IE only has troubles when the element is naturally a block-level element.

Comment: @Box9 That's really useful to know. So it can be used on `span`s any time?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` or their natural (default) display of inline.. though you can give the inline-block a width and height

Comment: what if the text content overflows.

Answer (score 4):

Try `display: inline-block;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah By Default Spans will show up next to each other, it all depends on the width of the element containing them.  If someone were to re-size the browser or you shrunk the containing div their would be a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline;` and this will achieve what you want.